# Performing pairwise aggregation functions on pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with roughly 500 columns. I can easily compute a correlation matrix on this data using `df.corr()`. However, I would like to know more than just the correlation for each pairwise column comparison. Specifically, I want to know how many rows in my source DataFrame had non-null records for both columns in the pair, so that I know the number of records used to calculate the correlation. The DataFrame is sparse enough that some correlations may be calculated over only a few null values while others may have thousands of contibuting data points.

Example Table:

| Index | feature 1 | feature 2 | feature 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 |  | 3 |
| b |  | 7 | 2 |
| c | 1 |  |  |
| d | 3 | 1 | 9 |

Desired Output:

| -- | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| feature1 | 3 | 1 (*) | 2 |
| feature2 | 1 (*) | 2 | 2 (**) |
| feature3 | 2 | 2 (**) | 3 |

This desired output shows me that the combination of 'feature1' and 'feature2' have only one row (*) where both have non-null values, but the combination of 'feature2' and 'feature3' have two rows (**) where both have non-null values.

I'm thinking some combination of `df.melt` and `df.pivot` could accomplish this, but I haven't found the right approach yet. I really don't want to iterate. I tried this, but with 500+ pairwise columns, it is never going to be fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a dot product on the features dataset as shown below:

```
a = 0 + ~df.isna()
a.T @ a
           feature 1  feature 2  feature 3
feature 1          3          1          2
feature 2          1          2          2
feature 3          2          2          3
```

Comment: gotcha. I'll get back in my box now :)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the existence of matrix math!